# What IP ranges to allow through firewall for IBM Watson API Gateway?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-watson, watson

We are running an internal application which needs to connect to IBM Watson. Our Firewall team is looking for the IP Ranges we should allow for communication with Bluemix.

```
Name       Geoortung        Kunde   Bereitstellung   Domäne               CF-API-Endpunkt                  Typ
eu-de      Germany          IBM     Production       eu-de.bluemix.net    https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net    public
```

I found a very useful webpage, but there is no information regarding the API Gateway in Frankfurt.

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/what-ip-ranges-do-i-allow-through-firewall

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The Watson APIs hosts depend on where your service was instantiated.

- `us-south`: `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net`,
- `eu-de`.  `https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net`

You only need to enable requests to the host where you Watson service instance is running. Make sure you use the URL and not the IP because it may change.